# MvvmCross custom UITextField twoway not updating

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, mvxbind

I have an UIDatePickerTextField created.
This is an subclass of UITextField.

**Functional**

When a user clicks on the textfield, a popup datepicker will be shown.
The user can select a date and click done. The value will be set to the textfield and its done.

In my view I use:

```
set.Bind(PickerTextField).For(x => x.Text).To(vm => vm.SelectedValue).TwoWay();
```

In the picker class i have implemented the interface `IMvxBindable` so have the properties `BindingContext` and `DataContext`.

When the user clicks done the click event is catched and handles the last steps

```
private void DoneButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideView();
    DateTime userSelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(_datePickerControl.Date.ToString());
    Text = userSelectedDate.ToString();
    SendActionForControlEvents(UIControlEvent.ValueChanged);
}
```

But for some reason the Text property is correctly set and visible, but the ViewModel set is not triggered. What do I wrong and how can I fix this? I would prevent using the ViewModel inside this control to keep it generic.